# [VBA][excel] Occurred error When Using 'Japanese - Katakana' in 'inStr'

Tags: vba, excel

I'm Korean Data analyst. I Used Korean version Windows 7 and OS.

I have a some problem about `instr` in VBA (Excel).
In normal case,
`instr` is generate accurate number at "C2" indicating starting point number at "A2" string

Here is normal sample:
[image: Alphabet]

Even Korean, and Japanese (hiragana) have no problem too.
Please excuse me I can't more sample 
because I have not enough reputation point this in this site.

But, there is always occur error when I use Japanese-Katakana
The error message is below sentence.

> '7' runtime error has occurred, Not enough memory

Refer to this sample:
[image: The error case - Japanese - (Katakana)]

I have embarrassed about this only one error
and trying to solve this problem,
but still don't know how.

I hope Anyone advice me good opinion and solution.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please insert the characters used editing your post? So people can copy and replicate the problem?

Comment: Many Thanks, I think  'pnuts''s advice is maybe answer,   There is no problem if unit test result is 'instrB'. i will final test with real source, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to replicate this issue, in my English Excel 2013/Win7.

However, I have seen such issue before in old excel version, and most probably, below should work.

1. Please change function "InStr" to "InStrb", and see whether it works

> ```
> Sub instr()
> Range("C2") = InStrB(1, Range("A2"), Range("B2"), 1)
> End Sub
> ```

2. Or you might want to do StrConv(string, vbUnicode) first before you call InStr function.

> ```
> Sub instr()
> Range("C2") = InStr(1, StrConv(Range("A2"), vbUnicode), StrConv(Range("B2"), vbUnicode), 1)
> End Sub
> ```

Whatever approach you selected, the return position value need be divided by two, if the input string is not Half-width chars. (Half-width chars are already gone in recent excel, and I suppose your excel is too old. Upgrading it is the best choice.)