# How to Solve "Out of Memory" when applying InStr to Japanese characters?

Tags: vba, outlook, out-of-memory

When I process emails in a folder I get "Out of Memory" error.

Searching online I see many suggests to clear the memory, so I added code like below:

```
Set objItem = Nothing
Set objMailItem = Nothing
Redim arrLines(0)
```

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnStart_Click()
  Dim StartDate As Date
  Dim EndDate As Date
  
  StartDate = DateValue("October 1, 2015")
  EndDate = DateValue("January 28, 2023")
  
  Call ProcessOrderEmails(StartDate, EndDate)
End Sub

Sub ProcessOrderEmails(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date)
    Dim objCurFolder As Folder
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim objMailItem As MailItem
    Dim nCSVFileNum As Integer
      
    '   Create the CSV file
    nCSVFileNum = FreeFile

    If Dir("E:\Temp\OrderStat.csv") <> "" Then
      Kill ("E:\Temp\OrderStat.csv")
    End If
    
    Open "E:\Temp\OrderStat.csv" For Output Lock Write As #nCSVFileNum
    
    '   Get statistics
    Set objCurFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
    
    For Each objItem In objCurFolder.Items
        If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then
            Set objMailItem = objItem
            
            ' Check if the mail is in the date range
            If (objMailItem.SentOn >= StartDate) And (objMailItem.SentOn <= EndDate) Then
              Select Case objMailItem.SenderEmailAddress
                Case "automated@mycommerce.com"
                  Print #nCSVFileNum, ProcessRegNowOrderEmail(objMailItem)
              End Select
            End If
        End If
        
        ' Set objItem to nothing to free memory
        Set objItem = Nothing
        Set objMailItem = Nothing
    Next
    
    '   Close the file
    Close nCSVFileNum
End Sub

Private Function ReplaceNewLine(strText As String, strNewLine As String) As String
  ReplaceNewLine = Replace(strText, vbCrLf, strNewLine)
  ReplaceNewLine = Replace(ReplaceNewLine, vbCr, strNewLine)
  ReplaceNewLine = Replace(ReplaceNewLine, vbLf, strNewLine)
End Function

Private Function SplitLines(strText As String) As Variant
  SplitLines = Split(ReplaceNewLine(strText, vbNewLine), vbNewLine)
End Function

' strEntryName should include :, like this RegNow OrderItemID:
Private Function GetEntryValue(strEntryLine As String, strEntryName As String, ByRef strEntryValue) As Boolean
  Dim strLine As String
  
  ' Initialize result to False by default
  GetEntryValue = False
  
  ' Parse the line
  strLine = ReplaceNewLine(Trim(strEntryLine), "")
  
  If InStr(1, strLine, strEntryName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    strEntryValue = Trim(Replace(strLine, strEntryName, "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare))
    GetEntryValue = True
  End If
End Function

Private Function ProcessRegNowOrderEmail(objMailItem As MailItem) As String
  Dim arrLines() As String
  Dim strLine As String
  Dim strOrderID As String
  Dim strProduct As String
  Dim strProfit As String
  Dim I As Integer

  arrLines = SplitLines(objMailItem.Body)
  
  For I = LBound(arrLines, 1) To UBound(arrLines, 1)
    Call GetEntryValue(arrLines(I), "RegNow OrderItemID:", strOrderID)
    Call GetEntryValue(arrLines(I), "Product Name:", strProduct)
    Call GetEntryValue(arrLines(I), "Profit:", strProfit)
  Next I
  
  ProcessRegNowOrderEmail = "RegNow," & strOrderID & "," & strProduct & "," & strProfit
  
  ReDim arrLines(0)
End Function
```

Sample email to be processed:

```
********** DO NOT REPLY TO THIS EMAIL **********

*** Transaction Identification ***
Date:               2017-03-14 02:14:14 (Pacific Standard Time) 
RegNow OrderID:     XXXXXX-XXXXX
RegNow OrderItemID: XXXXXX-XXXXX

*** Gift Information ***
Gift:               no
Pickup:             no

*** Product Information ***
Item #:             #####-#
Product Name:       My Product
Quantity:           1
Tax:                0.00 USD
Total:              199.95 USD
Profit:             189.15
```

---

The error is caused by the following line:

```vb
If InStr(1, strLine, strEntryName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
```

when strLine contains Japanese characters:

```
Address2: パティオたまプラーザ308
```

Searching online, I find similar posts:
[[VBA][excel] Occurred error When Using 'Japanese - Katakana' in 'inStr'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152417/vbaexcel-occurred-error-when-using-japanese-katakana-in-instr)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/06df9b54-ad75-4c18-9577-84e52b6e03a1/how-can-i-use-the-japanese-for-instr-vba-?forum=exceldev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to see how labels you are not interested in are processed.

This code will process specified labels only.

```vb
Option Explicit

Function ParseTextLinePair(strSource As String, strLabel As String)

    ' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/dd492012(v=office.12)

    Dim intLocLabel As Integer
    Dim intLocCRLF As Integer
    Dim intLenLabel As Integer
    Dim strText As String

    ' locate the label in the source text
    intLocLabel = InStr(strSource, strLabel)
    intLenLabel = Len(strLabel)
    
    If intLocLabel > 0 Then
        intLocCRLF = InStr(intLocLabel, strSource, vbCrLf)
        If intLocCRLF > 0 Then
            intLocLabel = intLocLabel + intLenLabel
            strText = Mid(strSource, intLocLabel, intLocCRLF - intLocLabel)
        Else
            intLocLabel = Mid(strSource, intLocLabel + intLenLabel)
        End If
    End If
    
    ParseTextLinePair = Trim(strText)
    
End Function

Private Function ProcessRegNowOrderEmail_Label(objMailItem As MailItem) As String
    
    Dim strOrderID As String
    Dim strProduct As String
    Dim strProfit As String
    
    strOrderID = ParseTextLinePair(objMailItem.body, "RegNow OrderItemID:")
    strProduct = ParseTextLinePair(objMailItem.body, "Product Name:")
    strProfit = ParseTextLinePair(objMailItem.body, "Profit:")

    ProcessRegNowOrderEmail_Label = "RegNow," & strOrderID & "," & strProduct & "," & strProfit

End Function
```

Replace

```
Print #nCSVFileNum, ProcessRegNowOrderEmail(objMailItem)
```

with

```
Print #nCSVFileNum, ProcessRegNowOrderEmail_Label(objMailItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently memory allocated to `objItem` in a `For Each` cannot be freed.

Change to an indexed `For Next` so there is no `objItem`.

```vb
Sub ProcessOrderEmails(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date)

    Dim objCurFolder As Folder
    Dim objMailItem As MailItem
    Dim nCSVFileNum As Integer
      
    '   Create the CSV file
    nCSVFileNum = FreeFile

    If dir("E:\Temp\OrderStat.csv") <> "" Then
      Kill ("E:\Temp\OrderStat.csv")
    End If
    
    Open "E:\Temp\OrderStat.csv" For Output Lock Write As #nCSVFileNum
    
    '   Get statistics
    Set objCurFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.currentFolder
    
    Dim curFolderItems As Items
    Set curFolderItems = objCurFolder.Items
    
    Dim curFolderItemsCount As Long
    curFolderItemsCount = curFolderItems.count
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 1 To curFolderItemsCount
    
        If TypeOf curFolderItems(i) Is MailItem Then
        
            Set objMailItem = curFolderItems(i)
            
            With objMailItem
                
                ' Check if the mail is in the date range
                If (.SentOn >= StartDate) And (.SentOn <= EndDate) Then
                    
                    Select Case .senderEmailAddress
                        Case "automated@mycommerce.com"
                            Print #nCSVFileNum, ProcessRegNowOrderEmail(objMailItem)
                        
                    End Select
                End If
            
            End With
            
            ' free memory
            Set objMailItem = Nothing
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    '   Close the file
    Close nCSVFileNum
End Sub
```

Appears there is something else involved. With your original code using `objItem` I can generate a file with over 30,000 entries.

Unlikely this will be any better but rather than assigning `objMailItem`, you could use `curFolderItems(i)` directly.

```vb
Sub ProcessOrderEmails(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date)

    Dim objCurFolder As Folder
    Dim nCSVFileNum As Integer
    
    Dim pathFile As String
    pathFile = "E:\Temp\OrderStat.csv"
        
    '   Create the CSV file
    nCSVFileNum = FreeFile
    Debug.Print nCSVFileNum
    
    If dir(pathFile) <> "" Then
        Kill pathFile
    End If
    
    Open pathFile For Output Lock Write As #nCSVFileNum
            
    '   Get statistics
    Set objCurFolder = Application.ActiveExplorer.currentFolder
    
    Dim curFolderItems As Items
    Set curFolderItems = objCurFolder.Items
    
    Dim curFolderItemsCount As Long
    curFolderItemsCount = curFolderItems.count
            
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim j As Long
    
    ' for testing the limit
    'For j = 1 To Int(1000 / curFolderItemsCount) + 1
    
        For i = 1 To curFolderItemsCount
        
            If TypeOf curFolderItems(i) Is MailItem Then
            
                Dim n As Long
                n = n + 1
                Debug.Print n
                
                With curFolderItems(i)
                    
                    ' Check if the mail is in the date range
                    If (.SentOn >= StartDate) And (.SentOn <= EndDate) Then
                        
                        'Select Case .senderEmailAddress
                            'Case "automated@mycommerce.com"
                                Print #nCSVFileNum, ProcessRegNowOrderEmail(curFolderItems(i))
                          
                        'End Select
                    End If
                    
                End With
            End If
            
        Next
        
    'Next
    
    '   Close the file
    Close nCSVFileNum
End Sub
```

Comment: I try your codes. It takes longer to run, but after processing 476 emails, it still report "Out of memory" error.

Comment: Looks like there was not much of an improvement. Appears there is something else involved. With your original code I can generate a file with over 20,000 entries.

Comment: That's strange. What is your Outlook version? I am using Outlook 2010(64bit) + Win7(64bit). Also is it possible to trace the memory usage when debugging?

Comment: I figure out the problem, there is a line containing Japanese characters, as below:Address2:           パティオたまプラーザ308, then using InStr(1, strLine, strEntryName, vbTextCompare) on this line will cause out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

After testing for several times, I find out

For Japanese characters in TextBox1.Text, call InStr with vbTextCompare will cause "Out of memory":

```
nPos = InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, "Address2", vbTextCompare)
```

But with vbBinaryCompare, everything is fine:

```
nPos = InStr(TextBox1.Text, "Address2")
nPos = InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, "Address2")
nPos = InStr(1, TextBox1.Text, "Address2", vbBinaryCompare)
```

Thanks to all of your great helps!